# Get Date from SQL table

Tags: java, sql, date, netbeans

I store my Java application date in database as string. NOT IN DATE FORMAT. One place I want to get this date 2013_12_9. But no respond from server. Can I do this or should I use DATE format in SQL. I can't move to date format. Any solution for this?

I cant deal with other date values but why this:

```
select * from grn_final where date  between '"+date+"' and  '"+date1+"'
```

date means beginning date date1 is ending date. No respond when I choose above date

Comment: why are you using + as suffix and prefix in date and date1

Comment: You should *absolutely* change your database schema to use a `DateTime` field or whatever your database supports. Also, don't construct your SQL dynamically like that - use parameterized SQL to avoid spurious conversions and SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @jon can refer some ques on SO reg this "use parameterized SQL to avoid spurious conversions and SQL injection attacks"

Comment: @sankrish: Search for "parameterized SQL" or "SQL injection attack" and you'll get *lots* of hits.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha It means he is passing the values dyanamically .. Might be from his JSP

Comment: thank you I will change like that..But is there any way to convert or get string date value..

Comment: yes I get the date from date choosers and check it..

Comment: post ur servlet , you might get some help

Comment: you know when I enter 2013_12_8 or 2013_12_10 or 2013_11_9 or any date beside 2013_12_9 it works..Only this date(2013_12_9) no support..But exactly that date not a range value it means 2013_12_9 date onle it returns data related to 2013_12_9 and 2013_12_10 too

Comment: Never ever store dates as varchar columns. Just don't - And you should mention the DBMS you are using (Postgres? Oracle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be better using date format instead of char. But if you can't change it, i think you should cast your date in the select (depends on your DBMS).

For instance for Oracle:

```
select * from grn_final where to_date(date, 'YYYY_MM_DD') between to_date('2013_12_9', 'YYYY_MM_DD') and  to_date('2013_12_10', 'YYYY_MM_DD');
```

But this is not very optimized.